# Are maximal ideals and principal ideals independent?

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains

How can I show that the properties *maximal* and *principal* can be true independently for an ideal?

I can find one example of each:

1. A maximal principal ideal
2. A maximal non-principal ideal
3. A non-maximal principal ideal
4. A non-maximal non-principal ideal

Is there a shortcut?

Comment: I think you would get more from thinking through this yourself, but I'll just remind you that a lot of the easy rings have no non-principal ideals at all. Probably the simplest ring that could possibly furnish examples to 2&3 is $\Bbb Z[x]$. (I suppose some people would object that $\Bbb C[x,y]$ is simpler, but remember that $\Bbb C[x]$ is not good enough!). Non-maximal ideals are much easier to come across.

Comment: Do you want a single ring in which all four examples can be found, or just one ring and one ideal for each example (so some examples may take place in the same rings, but others may not)?

Comment: I want to reduce the effort in showing that the properties are independent. 4 examples works but can it be done with fewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest examples come from algebraic geometry.

An example of a principal ideal that is maximal is given by $\langle x\rangle \subset k[x]$, which corresponds to the zero point in $\mathbb{A}_k$ and thus is maximal.

An example of a principal non maximal ideal is given by $\langle 0\rangle\subset \mathbb{Z}$.

For a maximal non principal ideal take $\langle x,y\rangle \subset k[x,y]$.

For something that is neither maximal nor principal, take the vanishing of two polynomials which does not consist of only one point.